# How to transfer UTM coordinates to Euclidean coordinate system?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates, utm

I get the coordinates of objects in the UTM format:

```
"coordinates": [
                [
                    4631430.35,
                    396976.54
                ],
                [
                    4631428.01,
                    396972.19
                ],
                [
                    4631430.24,
                    396970.98
                ],
                [
                    4631432.59,
                    396975.33
                ]
            ]
```

Also, I have the UTM reference => 32N.

How can I transform these coordinates to the Euclidean coordinate system? Which additional data may I need to do it?
I am looking for open-source Python libraries that can do such transformation.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Since all projected coordinate systems ***are*** Euclidean, your question is unclear. Please [Edit] the question to specify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The coordinates appear to be listed in northing, easting order, which is unusual.